reconnecting (failed to send authentication request: failed to fetch CRL. errors encountered: read tcp read: connection reset by peer)
[Terminal SS]: (https://i.sstatic.net/82VeASUT.png)
I had run this command
ngrok http 7000

can anyone help me with this ?
ngrok diagnose

Testing ngrok connectivity...
Internet Connectivity
Name Resolution
Auto (lowest latency)
Name Resolution
Localhost Connectivity
Ngrok Connectivity - Region: Auto (lowest latency)
Errors and warnings encountered during diagnostics:

Diagnostics

Connectivity

Err: No tunnel servers could establish a TLS connection.
(NGROK_ERR_8008)


connect.ngrok-agent.com (13.232.27.141:443)

Warn: Failed to establish TLS connection to connect.ngrok-agent.com
with error: failed to fetch CRL. errors encountered: read tcp
192.168.11.87:33496->108.159.61.14:80: read: connection reset by
peer. Possible Man-in-the Middle.
(NGROK_ERR_8003)
Err: Failed to establish TLS connection to 13.232.27.141 with error:
failed to fetch CRL. errors encountered: read tcp
192.168.11.87:33496->108.159.61.14:80: read: connection reset by
peer. Possible Man-in-the Middle.
(NGROK_ERR_8003)







Error establishing ngrok connection:
No tunnel servers could establish a TLS connection.your text
(NGROK_ERR_8008)
Report written to /tmp/ngrok-diagnose2187792939/diagnose.json

You can try https://pinggy.io instead. Does the same thing.

yes but it is free only for 1 month
